# Adding Pair of Drop downs Dynamically using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Am working on a ASP.NET MVC4 project. In UI i need to bring a following kind of sequence/cascading dropdowns.![Cannot add image since less reputation][1]

When "Left Table" and "Right Table" drop downs changed-show the tables column(s) names of respective tables using ajax as  2 dropdowns Named MasterKeys and SlaveKeys (from respecte tableNames) .when add button pressed load same coumnNames to two more dropdowns below to previously added.

I need to know how to add pair of dropdowns each time when add clicked(adding Multile joinKeys to join tables).That too to the same div with new line but with same content as previous (above it) so that they fall below the previous.
I tried this using jquery/javascript-adding dynamic elements.

Comment: post sample of your HTML here or on jsFiddle

Comment: First i added two tales as Left and Right Tables as $('#showTables').append('Left Table<select id="MasterTableNames" onchange="SelectMasterKeys()"><option>Select</option></select>');
        $('#showTables').append('Right Table<select id="SlaveTableNames" onchange="SelectSlaveKeys()"><option>Select</option></select>');
  then populated them using ajax